# How to record a clean video from the Hololens 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

so I just started deploying my first (fairly small and basic) unity project onto my Hololens 2. For documentation purposes I now want to record a clean mixed reality video of me interaction live with my app. Yes I know, there are three basic functions for capturing the mixed reality video feed:

1. Starting to record on the Hololens locally by pressing both of the volume buttons.
2. Using the "Microsoft Hololens" App on my computer to start recording
3. Using the "Microsoft Hololens" App on my computer and capture the Live View of the Hololens with OBS or some other recording software

Sadly in all those three option im running into the same problem: The Video feed is lagging very hard. The video has no stable fps and showing what I implemented is nearly impossible. And all of that in a very small an basic project.

Do you have any recommendations in capturing a clean video? Is it possible to connect the Hololens via USB-C cable and somehow capture the screen? Or how can I get rid of the lags?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal) to record what you see in real-time on a PC. I’ve tested it on the HoloLens2 and it’s stable.

To record mixed reality videos, please navigate to Device Portal->View->Mixed Reality Capture, then make sure you select “Render from Camera” and click on “Record”.

For more information about how to create mixed reality photos and videos, you can refer to [Capture, record, and share mixed reality photos and videos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/holographic-photos-and-videos).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes that surely works! Sadly my application features the in-app use of the hololens camera. When I start the application the MR-capture stops. Same goes for the Live preview mode. Obviously thats intended by microsoft: If an app requests ExclusiveControl access to the photo/video camera, built-in MRC will automatically stop using the photo/video camera so the app's request will succeed. Is there another way of capturing while the camera is already used via the app itself?

Comment: Hi, would it be convenient for you to tell me what you used to implement the in-app use of the HoloLens camera? I suspect it might be related to the issue you encountered. I used [WebCamTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html) to create a demo and conducted a test recording of a mixed reality video via Device Portal, which was successful.

Comment: I inplemented a ImageTarget with the Vuforia package. Also I wrote a custom script to take a photo.